# How can I change the favicon on my Superset Application?

Tags: apache-superset

I’m setting up a new Superset for a client and I would like to display his company logo in the browser with the favicon.

It's not into the superset/config.py, there we can change the icon of Superset but not the favicon

I am thinking about Flask or Appbuilder answers but not sure...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply change the favicon.png file contained in the superset/assets/images folder.

Comment: If you are using image and standard container setup using docker then in container of image  `incubator-superset_superset` you need to replace favicon.png at /app/superset/static/assets/images

Comment: From superset version 0.37
favicon is at `/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/static/assets/images/favicon.png`
logo is ar `/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/static/assets/image/superset-logo-horiz.png`

Answer (score 4):

With latest version of Superset (1.4.1).
You can add below values in the custom config (superset_config.py).

```
# Visual Customizations
APP_NAME = "CUSTOM_APP_NAME"
APP_ICON = "/static/assets/images/your_custom_logo_horiz.png"
APP_ICON_WIDTH = 200
# Path for routing when APP_ICON image is clicked
LOGO_TARGET_PATH = '/' # Forwards to /superset/welcome/home
LOGO_TOOLTIP = "Go Home" # Text displayed when hovering.
FAVICONS = [{"href": "/static/assets/images/custom_favicon.png"}]
```